# Node Mocha / Chai Unit Tests - Compare array of objects regardless of order

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to do some unit tests comparing an array of results to an array it should look like, unfortunately the results come from an api with delays so the order of objects is not always the same, which causes the test to fail:

**Simplified example**

```
var a = [
    {name: 'Joe', age: 35},
    {name: 'Steve', age: 30},
]

//assume we got the result in this order
var b = [
    {name: 'Steve', age: 30},
    {name: 'Joe', age: 35},
]

expect(a).to.deep.equal(b) //Fails
```

My current workaround is to do this:

```
expect(a.length).to.equal(b.length);
for(let item of b){
    expect(a).to.deep.contain(item);
}
```

But I'm looking for a way to do a deep comparison directly without regard to order in Mocha / Chai, is it possible?

**update:**
This is a bit of a hack, but it might helps in case anyone needs it, you can put the whole thing in a try / catch and on error use deep contain:

```
try{
    expect(a).to.have.deep.members(b);
}catch(e){
    expect(a).to.deep.equal(b);
}
```

If the first test fails, it runs the second which will also fail but prints out the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
expect(a).to.have.deep.members(b)
```

Documentation: http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members

Comment: Thanks, this does work but if the test fails it doesn't show the differences (like deep contain), is there any way to force that?

Comment: @Mankind1023 I don't think that's possible :(